# C undesired array output for Turtle graphic

Tags: c, arrays, turtle-graphics

trying to finish a homework assignment where basically it is asking us to create a turtle graphic program. The program will take commands and then process the commands at the end. So I though I would scanf the commands into an array using a loop then process the commands by going through the same array and processing the commands.

```
int i = 0, j;
int command = 0;
int floor[50][50];
int arrCommand[500];
int valCommand = arrCommand[i--];
int valFloor = floor[floorSize][floorSize];

for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    arrCommand[i] = 0;
}

do {
    printf("Please enter a command:\n");
    printf("[1] - Pen Up\n");
    printf("[2] - Pen Down\n");
    printf("[3] - Turn Right\n");
    printf("[4] - Turn Left\n");
    printf("[5],[i] - Move forward i places\n");
    printf("[6] - Print current 50x50 frame\n");
    printf("[9] - End Program\n");

    //loop to initialize commands into array
    for (i = 0; arrCommand[i - 1] != 9; i++) {

        scanf("%d", &arrCommand[i]);
        printf("%d\n\n", arrCommand[i]);
        if (arrCommand[i] == 5) {
            scanf(",%d", &arrCommand[i]);
        }
    }

    for ( i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", arrCommand[i]);
    }

} while (command != 9);
```

You could ignore the `do` loop.

After user inputs the commands the next loop is to display the sequence of commands in the array. Why does `23469` show as one element and `-858993460` show as the next element? I would expect it to keep printing the inputted commands.

```
Please enter a command:
[1] - Pen Up
[2] - Pen Down
[3] - Turn Right
[4] - Turn Left
[5],[i] - Move forward i places
[6] - Print current 50x50 frame
[9] - End Program
2
2

3
3

4
4

6
6

9
9

23469-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460- 
858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460- 
858993460- 
858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460Please enter a command:
[1] - Pen Up
[2] - Pen Down
[3] - Turn Right
[4] - Turn Left
[5],[i] - Move forward i places
[6] - Print current 50x50 frame
[9] - End Program
```

Comment: how is `arrCommand` declared?

Comment: It feels like you're walking off the end of the array.

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%d", &arrCommand[i]);
        printf("%d\n\n", arrCommand[i]);
        if (arrCommand[i] == 5) {
            scanf(",%d", &arrCommand[i]);
        }`  this results, when the user input is 5, that the command '5' will be overlayed by the second number.

Comment: where is the variable `command` being set?

Comment: please post  a [mcve] so we can reproduce (and debug) the problem

Comment: regarding: `for ( i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", arrCommand[i]);
    }` what happens when less than 25 commands have been entered by the user?  Per the posted code, then uninitialized values from the array `arrCommand` will be printed.

Comment: @user3629249 I added my declarations and also code where I initialized first 50 elements of arrCommand to 50.

Comment: `floor` is a well known function, exposed by the header file: `math.h`  Suggest using a unique name, like `myFloor`

Comment: regarding: `int arrCommand[500];
int valCommand = arrCommand[i--];
int valFloor = floor[floorSize][floorSize];`   the value in `i` is 0 so the value after the expression: `arrCommand[i--]` will be -1.   The value set into the variable `valCommand` will be trash because the array `arrCommandn[]` is not initialized to any known value.  the array `floor[][]` is not set to any known values, so the `valFloor` variable is getting trash.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can help you debug the problem

Comment: the value `floorSize` is not set anywhere in the posted code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one thing

```
for (i = 0; arrCommand[i - 1] != 9; i++) {
```

isn't going to work when `i` is 0 because you will try to access `arrCommand[-1]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change like this to work,

```
//loop to initialize commands into array
    for (i = 1; arrCommand[i - 1] != 9; i++) {  // or for (i = 0; arrCommand[i] != 9; i++) Need to change so that it check value from 0 index of arrCommand

        scanf("%d", &arrCommand[i]);
        printf("%d\n\n", arrCommand[i]);
        if (arrCommand[i] == 5) {
            scanf("%d", &arrCommand[i]); //here you need to remove ','
        }
    }
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Is the `,` an issue?  For one, his example never inputs a `5`, so this code in not executed.  Second, I think the input expected when `5` is used is `5,x`, that is, `5` followed by a comma, followed by another int, so the comma is needed.

Comment: @StephenDocy are you sure `,` will copy into `aarCommand[5]` ? i don't think it will.

Comment: @ThiruShetty, the comma appears to be needed for `scanf()` to know to skip over it, otherwise it fails.  Try it both ways and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Let's restructure this program.  First, when we encounter a '5', we'll store the 5 command, and it's argument as the following value in `arrCommand`, so we know what it is and why it's there. (Consider what an input of '5,6' would do to your current logic.)  We don't need to initialize `arrCommand`, we only examine values we set, so I've tossed that.  Your printing logic should be outside, after the input loop so I've moved that.  Your control logic in the `for` loop doesn't work so I've switched to a simpler `while` loop.  You outer `do` loop is an infinite loop so I've removed it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main() {
    int i = 0, command = -1;
    int arrCommand[500];

    printf("Please enter a command:\n");
    printf("[1] - Pen Up\n");
    printf("[2] - Pen Down\n");
    printf("[3] - Turn Right\n");
    printf("[4] - Turn Left\n");
    printf("[5],[i] - Move forward i places\n");
    printf("[6] - Print current 50x50 frame\n");
    printf("[9] - End Program\n");

    // loop to initialize commands into array

    while (command != 9) {

        int count = scanf("%d", &command);
        assert(count == 1);

        arrCommand[i++] = command;

        if (command == 5) {
            count = scanf(",%d", &arrCommand[i++]);
            assert(count == 1);
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        if (arrCommand[j] == 5) {
            printf("%d,%d ", arrCommand[j], arrCommand[j + 1]);
            j++;
        } else {
            printf("%d ", arrCommand[j]);
        }
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**USAGE**

```
> ./a.out
Please enter a command:
[1] - Pen Up
[2] - Pen Down
[3] - Turn Right
[4] - Turn Left
[5],[i] - Move forward i places
[6] - Print current 50x50 frame
[9] - End Program
1
3
6
5,100
4 
9
1 3 6 5,100 4 9 
>
```